# How to open download dialog box after redirection to another page

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

I am working in asp.net 2.0 and want that when user clicks on Download button he/she is redirected to another page and on that page download dialog box opens for downloading file and if user clicks on save button than it starts downloading.

I have searched a lot for that and found the link below:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/107b2c17-07fe-4a15-ad81-dcb31e1e9c84/
But don't have the idea of complete implementation of the code.Can you help me out by giving the complete source code for that.I will be very thankful.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using asp.net 2.0 and want to redirect a user; any particular reason you tagged your question with 'ajax'?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222034/how-does-sourceforges-download-page-work), but please, do not not make your users suffer that much. Donwload link should be just that -- a download link.

Answer (score 0):

putting something like this on your target page should work:

```
<h1>Your Content</h1>
<script>
  window.location.href = "http://server.com/download.exe"
</script>
```

Your Content stays there, and download dialog opens.

cheers sascha